# Pixels while texture painting

Tags: faces, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

I come to a problem while texture painting. The lines and strokes are all pixelized and looks very ugly.

I tried to double/quadruple(2048px X 2048px/4096px X 4096px) the size of the image in the UV Editor window and reassign the new image to the image texture which is linked into a Principled BSDF, but even this seems not to get drawing sharper.

I even tried to enlarge the mesh to maybe cover more pixels but nothing works.

Is there anything we can do for this?

**[Edit]**

I figured that the faces ratio are not correct in the UV Map. I don't know if it may be part of the problem.

[image]

Comment: What does your UV mapping look like in the UV Editor compared to the pixels underneath in the image texture?

Comment: the face is deformed, really tiny in the uv editor compared to the real face

Comment: Yes, the amount of pixels assigned per face will affect your painting result. Scale up the smaller faces or at least try a smart up unwrap to fill the image space as much as possible.

Comment: I tested with a picture from the internet which is way smaller than those I did and comes out better in details than painting. I might just paint my textures with another app and add them.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I guess what you're getting is the strokes on the left and what you want is the strokes on the right.

[image]

To get that make sure that the fallout is set to smooth or something similar
[image]

Comment: It's more when i use low pixel brushes like 1-3 pixels and being very close to to object, I think it might be due to the uv map. that faces are not properly set by the system. I edited my post with a picture of the uv map and the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I did not set my scale before unwrapping my UV. Go to Object Mode and select the item(s) to unwrap. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Scale*, then unwrap.

If you have already painted textures you will have to start again.